# Can't find boot-repair package for the newest version of Ubuntu

Tags: apt, boot-repair

After upgrading Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04, grub failed to load Ubuntu and threw the error `symbol 'grub_term_highlight_color' not found`. I followed the solution offered in the [Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1289977) but this failed for me, throwing the error `failed to get canonical path of /cow`.

Now, I'm trying to install Boot-Repair to fix this problem on a live pen-drive, using these commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

But after adding and updating the repositories, it shows `ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair` 404 Not Found error.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/yannubuntu/boot-repair/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Is this problem solvable or is there an alternative PPA for Boot-Repair?

Comment: did you face any problem by following the accepted answer?

Comment: Not at all, it might not be the most elegant solution but it works perfectly and it is the quickest solution.

Comment: The PPA doesn't have a package ready for Trusty. Just mail the maintainers.

Comment: After upgrade from 13.10 to 14.04 I was left with unbootable computer. My Configuration is Toshiba P875 laptop with Windows 8 preinstalled. Using bootable boot-repair.iso (http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) worked for me to.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> **Update:** The PPA currently offers updated packages for 14.04 and above.

## Workaround: install packages for an older release

It showed a 404 not found error because the PPA was not updated for the newer release (trusty). To install `boot-repair` in Ubuntu 14.04, run the below commands on terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
codename="$(lsb_release -cs)"
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/$codename/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-$codename.list"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Now use the `recommended repair` option to repair your grub and restart after boot-repair finished repairing.

Comment: Please, post the reason for downvotes.

Comment: why would some one down vote this! worked for me, thanks man!

Comment: after the last step (install -y boot repair)  cmd reach  "/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-g2slaunch.sh: line 33: hash: gksudo: not found
/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-g2slaunch.sh: line 35: hash: gksu: not found"   and displays a boot repair window saying "scanning systems(os-prober).This may take several minutes" ... :( But doesnt end ..Why ? :(

Comment: Now this answer was added to the [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) community page.

Comment: I think that those downvotes are because of "using saucy packages on trusty is bad, bebebe". Just ignore them. I got a downvote on another answer because of that reason. Fortunately I had no upvotes, so just deleted it.

Comment: @Danatela did you see the community wiki page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair. This answer was added to that because there is a major bug in the 14.04 grub package.

Comment: To anybody who wants to downvote this because  "using saucy packages on trusty is bad", consider that this answer is often the only option for many people. This worked for me, and was the only grub-repair option I had. There were also no bad sidefects of using it so I see no problem using saucy packages here.

Comment: You should now update your answer to serve the "utopic" distribution.

Comment: This fails for me on 14.04.1 with `gksudo: not found` and `gksu: not found`.  Doing an apt-get install gksu tells me `Package gksu is not available, but is referred to by another package.`

Comment: Why are you using `gksu` instead of `sudo` ?

Comment: I'm not.   boot-repair is.    I had to enable universe on my livecd to install gksu.   Hopefully that works.

Comment: yep, install gksu

Comment: It didn't work on the first try, but I did eventually get it to work.  I had to run dosfsck on the efi partition.   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091477/comments/14

Answer (score 6):

Update: There is a bug report on lp - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1289977

From the above bug report,

-Boot (14.04) from a pendrive
-Mount my root file system (where /boot is)

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
```

/dev/sdaX is the location of your /boot directory

-run: "sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt//boot /dev/sdX"

The exact command depends on if you have a separate boot partition

Separate /boot partition

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```

No separate /boot partition

```
grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

Then reboot with HDD

Three options:

1. Wait for the maintainer of the ppa to build a package for 14.04 . This is probably the slowest and least practical.
2. File a bug report with the against boot-repair asking for a 14.04 package. Will possibly be a bit faster.
3. Boot an older version of Ubuntu, 13.10, and run boot-repair. You will probably be just fine with an older version.

I suppose there is a 4th option - debug grub manually, what error message are you getting and tell us about your installation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After upgrading from 13.10 to 14.04 I got the grub error `error symbol 'grub_term_highlight_color' not found`. And when I try to make changes to grub from the terminal I get the message `error: failed to get canonical path of /cow'.
`

Comment: What about manually changing `trusty` to `saucy`? Yes, it isn't a clean method at all but should work.

Comment: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1289977

Comment: @Jobin - I would consider that on a live CD. There is a bug report and fix available as above.

Answer (score 2):

The first workaround mentioned in this bug report worked for me:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/boot-repair/+bug/1267702

Basically, you have to manually install three .deb packages: glade2script, boot-sav and then boot-repair (in this order). Use the most recent ones (the ones for saucy).

Answer (score 2):

Had the same error "symbol 'grub_term_highlight_color' not found", stuck at Grub rescue. Tried boot-repair (recommended option), but didn't work!

Solution: Downloaded bootable boot-repair.iso (http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) and made a bootable usb disk. Booted from it and connected to internet and started "Recommended Repair", then followed the instructions in a few steps (manually delete/uninstall grub and then re-install a new version), which worked!