# Upgrade problems (from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04)

Tags: grub2, upgrade, 14.04

I just upgraded my PC from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04. I followed each any every step, but after upgrading everything I clicked on the restart button to apply the changes, found myself stuck on a blank page saying :

```
error: symbol 'grub_term_highlight_color' not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I don't know what's going but I'm sure I'll get help from you guys. So please help me fix this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate: [boot repair on 14-04][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/449818/boot-repair-ppa-404-error-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1):

> error: symbol 'grub_term_highlight_color'

Is GRUB2 error.
Download Boot-Repair CD and try to fix GRUB from it. [Download](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A1st_option_%3a_get_a_CD_including_Boot-Repair)

Comment: could you please elaborate this for me. i dont quite understand this.

Comment: See this after burning iso to cd/ adding on pendrive and booting from there. See http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/ -After opening the "recommended" repair - it'll give you instructions.