# Windows 8.1 is not showing up in grub2 menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

I have a Toshiba Satellite C55 Series Laptop. I decided to install Ubuntu because I love Android. When I installed Ubuntu there was a Windows 8 option, but after I restarted my laptop windows 8 option was gone. I have already tried a lot of things like sudo update-grub or sudo update-grub2. Can anyone help. Thanks

Comment: Another user wrote a pretty long guide that helps with various Windows 8.1 issues. Check it out: http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/295286

Answer (score 2):

Install a package called "Boot Repair"

FYI:
Boot-Repair is a simple tool to repair frequent boot issues you may encounter in Ubuntu like when you can't boot Ubuntu after installing Windows or another Linux distribution, or when you **can't boot Windows after installing Ubuntu**, or when GRUB is not displayed anymore, some upgrade breaks GRUB, etc.

Kindly follow up this link!
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: how can i use it

Comment: Boot up your Ubuntu and follow the steps to install Boot Repair. It does have a GUI, so it won't be that hard.

Comment: I tried it and got this link   http://paste.ubuntu.com/8552647/

Comment: I assume you have two hdd, try to disable secure boot from bios. You can follow up this [Link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/472022/uefi-ubuntu-14-04-on-separate-hdd) for details/methods. Or try (--I know you already tried! --) a grub_update must do a trick