# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Boot-Repair Error

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I always like to start by apologizing just in case this is a duplicate question, but I don't really know what to ask, so I don't know what to look for. With that being said, I'm running a Lenovo V570 with 16GB of RAM and a 750GB HDD and want to run a single OS (no dual boot with Windows). I was running 12.04 LTS with no problem, but now that I'm trying to upgrade to 14.04 LTS it seems that I can't boot my computer. I am installing the OS from a DVD which I burned using the 64-bit *.iso file.

When I start it up I get an error `Could not open efi\boot\fallback.efi: 14` and then it brings up the GRUB menu for me to try Ubuntu without installing, install Ubuntu, etc.

I have successfully install Ubuntu but since it's not working, I boot into the trial version of Ubuntu and have run the Boot Repair per the accepted answer in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449818/cant-find-boot-repair-package-for-the-newest-version-of-ubuntu).

Looking at the GRUB options, it does show the EFI option and it is ticked, so I believe it's doing what it's supposed to be doing and not installing in Legacy mode. After the boot repair finishes, though, it tells me there's an error and gives me [this link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7561289/).

I'm not sure what to do with that information, though, because I'm not overly savvy with this kind of stuff.

Can anyone help with why I can't seem to boot after installing 14.04 LTS?

Comment: I've decided to just revert back to my 12.04 LTS OS and wait until 14.04 becomes a little more stable and just use sudo update-manager -d to upgrade to 14.04.