# Can't install ubuntu on surface pro since keyboard/touch doesn't work

Tags: system-installation, keyboard, surface

I'm trying to install ubuntu on my microsoft surface pro and I'm having issues installing as it seems my bluetooth keyboard and touch aren't working at all. I created a bootable usb and was able to boot from it but once I get to the main selection I can't even select to install. The surface pro only has one usb port so I'm unable to plug in a corded keyboard. Is there any possible work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

I found that bluetooth keyboards worked fine and were my saving grace when I was installing ubuntu on my surface 2, so it may be your specific keyboard that is causing issues. Maybe try a different bluetooth keyboard?

I was using a generically branded Adapt ADK-100 keyboard.

Alternatively, you can try turning on the on screen keyboard. To do this, you'll need to boot into live mode, start the OSK from the accessibility settings, and then launch the install.

If you're using the microsoft surface keyboard, then it's not bluetooth, it uses their special side connector, and needs a kernel patch to get it to work (or did, the last few updates I've done haven't required a manual kernel rebuild, so we may now be ok).

The patch in question:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2183946&page=2&p=12844865#post12844865

To build and install this kernel patch, follow these instructions:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

ignore the `fakeroot debian/rules editconfigs` line, and at that point instead go and modify the files as per the ubuntu forums code block, then continue with the process.

Comment: Yeah it's not the standard microsoft keyboard, although that's interesting that your bluetooth keyboard works. I'll try booting with the on-screen keyboard.

Comment: My experience is that when you get to the end of the install, you'll need to run boot repair as well. Have a look here: [boot-repair for 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449818/cant-find-boot-repair-package-for-the-newest-version-of-ubuntu)

Comment: Could you explain how to turn on the on screen keyboard from boot? I can't seem to find how

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you trying to install? I'll grab the ISO and check.

Comment: 14.04.1 LTS (latest)

Comment: Right, so in 14.04.1, when you get to the screen where you can choose between "try ubuntu" and "install ubuntu", in the top right there is a little white man in a blue dot. Click him, then click "on screen keyboard".

This will cause a set of four boxes arranged in a square to appear next to the little man, and should also make the on screen keyboard appear. If the on screen keyboard doesn't show up, try clicking the four boxes and going "show onboard".

Once you have the OSK, you can continue with the install, no need for the live environment.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in the top right corner, is your grub the same as mine: GNU GRUB version 2.02-beta2-9ubuntu1 ?

Comment: I'm not at the grub bootloader, I'm at [this screen](https://assets.ubuntu.com/sites/ubuntu/latest/u/img/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop/image-installdesktoplongtermsupport-1.jpg). Are you using a minimal install? You'll need to use a full DVD install, or you won't get the on screen keyboard as part of the installer.

Comment: I just downloaded the iso and loaded and created a bootable usb with the iso. Maybe it's the software I'm using to create the bootable usb? I'm using LinuxLive USB Creator what are you using?

Comment: I did my test by loading the DVD directly into virtualbox, but I definitely got the graphical screen when I installed it on my surface, and I used [unetbootn](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to make the USB.