# I can't install Ubuntu because the keyboard is disabled, how do i solve this?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, keyboard

I can't install Ubuntu because the keyboard is disabled, how do i solve this?

I tried to install Ubuntu alongside Windows7 to dual boot. But it stalls everytime because I can't fill  out my name on the 6th or 7th step.

I've tried this with both Ubuntu 8-ish and the most recent one 16-ish

Keyboard works under Win7.

laptop is an HP DV2 pavillion.

I don't have a corded keyboard, and getting one would take me 150$ cos of the half a days travel, so no.

i will try to start the OSK from the accessibility settings....

it says stdin: Not a typewriter

Comment: So how did you get to the 6th or 7th step without the keyboard ?

Comment: thank you both for the effort, how ever,  start the OSK from the accessibility settings worked for me. See here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/558617/cant-install-ubuntu-on-surface-pro-since-keyboard-touch-doesnt-work?rq=1

@George weeeeeeeeeeeeeeeell, because it didn't ask for kb input until the very end. I'd say '''DUH, OBVIOUSLY''' but since I'm raised right, I won't. ;)  ;)  ;)  ;)  <3<3<3

Answer (score 0):

You can use kickstart with ubuntu to do an automatic install. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KickstartCompatibility

Answer (score 0):

That's difficult to say anything about, not knowing what keyboard you have. But if the keyboard works in bios, pressing F2 or F11 to enter bios-setting, it should work in Ubuntu too.

Since you have come to enter your name, some kind of input must have worked to get you there. Try to load on-screen keyboard, and click through the installation with the mouse.

Comment: i didn't enter my name! this was the whole problem. Odd remark.